# Azure message bus trigger Function app - how to set the connection string?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

In Visual studio, you can easily crate a function app which triggers on a new message on a topic.  The code looks like this:

```
namespace streamsinfo
{
    public class gameInfoTrigger
    {
        private readonly ILogger<gameInfoTrigger> _logger;

        public gameInfoTrigger(ILogger<gameInfoTrigger> log)
        {
            _logger = log;
        }

        [FunctionName("gameInfoTrigger")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mytopic", "mysubscription", Connection = "streamEndpoint")]string mySbMsg)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");

        }
    }
}
```

The question is, where and how do we set the connection string to the service bus endpoint, for both running locally and running in Azure cloud?

Presumably "streamEndpoing" is some sort of env var containing the actual connection string? I tried hard coding the endpoint directly into the Connection=, but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Name you set to the Attribute refers to the Name of the setting containing the connection string.

For local Development you can add the setting to local.settings.json

When deployed to Azure you create the setting in the App Configuration section.

Comment: Interestingly, the connection string goes in the normal settings, not connection strings section.